# Search Widget Full Width

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-search, android-searchmanager

I'm targetting API level 8+ and I'd like to have a full width
search view on top of the action bar, expanded by default and not collapsable.
Here's what I did:

I've an ActionBar activity where I set inside onCreate:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

then onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);

    return true;
}
```

Here my search.xml inside menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="@string/search_product"
        myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        myapp:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

</menu>
```

and my searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_product"
    android:label="@string/searchable"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" >

</searchable>
```

This way, some extra space remains between back button and search widget.
Can you help me whit this?

[image: search widget left margin]

P.S. Why search icon is not INSIDE the widget? If I set setIconifiedByDefault to
true and then click on the icon, the image remains inside the text space...

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?